# Add menu option to SMS interface

Tags: android, sms

I'm looking for a way to add a new custom menu item to the SMS interface. The idea is add an option like "**Insert predefined message**", and control the predefined message from other application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Only by writing your own SMS client -- sorry!